# How to dynamically add options to optparser?

Tags: python, configuration, module, code-organization

I have a system, where you can modify, which modules will be loaded (and run; "module" is not necessarily python module, it can combine several modules). The program can run module A and B. Now, I want to have an option that every module can define (add) its own parameters. Let's say A wants to have -n and B wants to have -s for something. But there is one common parameter -c, which the main system itself needs. What is the best way to achieve this?

So far I have been using single optparse.OptionParser instance and passed it to every module, when they are initialized. Then the module can modify (add a new parameter) if needed.

Comment: Do you have any problems with the way you are currently doing it?

Comment: @sth - Current solution seems like a mess. First I pass the parser to module to add parameters. Later on I have to get the values for parameters. It's doable and kinda works. I'm just looking for more elegant solution if there is one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I had this problem I ended up using a class derived from `ArgumentParser` that added the ability to register callback functions that would be executed once the arguments were parsed:

```
import argparse

class ArgumentParser(argparse.ArgumentParser):
   def __init__(self, *p, **kw):
      super(ArgumentParser, self).__init__(*p, **kw)
      self._reactions = []
   def add_reaction(self, handler):
      self._reactions.append(handler)
   def parse_known_args(self, args=None, namespace=None):
      (args, argv) = super(ArgumentParser, self).parse_known_args(args, namespace)
      for reaction in self._reactions:
         reaction(args)
      return (args, argv)
```

This way the parser object still needs to be passed to all the modules to register their command line switches, but the modules can react to the switches "on their own":

```
def arguments_parsed(args):
   if args.datafile:
      load_stuff(args.datafile)

def add_arguments(ap):
   ap.add_argument('--datafile',
         help="Load additional input data")
   ap.add_reaction(arguments_parsed)
```

This uses `argparse`, but the same could probably be done with `optparse`.

It is not tested with advanced features like subparsers and probably won't work there, but could easily be extended to do so.

Comment: Thanks for the example, I will look into that. I currently have a module (conf) with an instance of my configuration class (variable name conf). This configuration class has the optparse object (variable optionparser). So, I can access it easily `conf.conf.optionparser.add_option(...)`. Before the main part starts running, I parse options to use them. Does this make sense?

Comment: Anyway, I will accept your answer, as it gave me some new ideas and the callback idea is valuable.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider moving to a library that supports the concept of *sub-parsers*, such as [argparse](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#sub-commands) (which deprecates optparse anyway), so that each library can create its own parser rules, and the main program can just combine them.

Comment: I'm stuck with python 2.6. And even if I used argparse, you still suggest me to use the same architecture where I send parser to each module (in this case it would be the parent parser)?

Comment: Subparsers only help if you want each module to implement a subcommand, like `svn commit` vs. `svn checkout` etc.. If you just want to add a command line switch subparsers don't help at all.